# C# Constructor parameter passing

Tags: c#, constructor

I currently restruct my program to be more object-orientated and I'm having trouble with the constructors of my objects.

All objects are stored in a database which has to be human-readable, so I figured it would be nice for the programmer to pass the constructor of an object the table or datarow directly and the object would get the values itself.

So, what I wanted to do was this:

```
public TestObject(Data.MyDataTable table) {
 // Some checks if the table is valid
 TestObject(table[0]);
}

public TestObject(Data.MyDataRow row) {
 // Some checks if the row is valid
 TestObject(row.Name, row.Value);
}

public TestObject(String name, String value) {
 // Some checks if the strings are valid
 _name = name;
 _value = value;
}
```

So, as you see, I want sort of a "constructor chain" that, depending on how the programmer calls it, the values are passed through and validated in each step. I tried it the way I wrote it, but it didn't work.

```
Error 'TestObject' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

I also tried writing `this.TestObject(...)` but no changes.

```
Error 'TestObject' does not contain a definition for 'TestObject' and
no extension method 'TestObject' accepting a first argument of type
'TestObject' could be found
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: "It didn't work". What didn't work? What were the issues?

Comment: @Oded: The exception message is clearly stated, and from the code it is easy to see what's the problem...

Comment: @gehho I added the exception after he asked. Nothing to blame ;)

Comment: Oh OK, I did not see an edit, that's why I commented. I found your question to be pretty clear, so I really wondered. @Oded: sorry... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Constructor chaining](http://www.csharp411.com/constructor-chaining/) works like that :

```
public TestObject(Data.MyDataTable table) : this(table[0])
{

}

public TestObject(Data.MyDataRow row) : this(row.Name, row.Value)
{

}

public TestObject(String name, String value)
{
 // Some checks if the strings are valid
 _name = name;
 _value = value;
}
```

Comment: @ApoY2K - You can catch the exception when constructing the `TestObject` object.

Comment: You can also do something like this to avoid that `null` or empty parameters throw exceptions: `public TestObject(Data.MyDataTable table) : this((table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0) ? table[0] : null)`

Answer (score 7):

You [chain constructors](http://www.csharp411.com/constructor-chaining/) like this:

```
public TestObject(Data.MyDataTable table) : this(table[0])
{

}

public TestObject(Data.MyDataRow row) : this(row.Name, row.Value)
{

}

public TestObject(String name, String value) 
{
 // Some checks if the strings are valid
 _name = name;
 _value = value;
}
```

Note: the use of the `this` keyword to indicate the current object, use of the parameters that are passed in to one constructor to the chained constructor.