# NullReferenceException using two constructor class

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I'm new here. I can't find solution to my problem anywhere. I'm writing a project to school. I have two forms. In first form, I have a DataGridView object, when I'm storing data in a SQL Server database. I'm passing usernames from DataGridView to second form using code:

```
List<string> usersList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewUsers.RowCount; i++)
{
    usersList.Add(dataGridViewUsers.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}

AddFileForm addFile = new AddFileForm(usersList);
addFile.Show();
```

In second form in have following code:

```
    private List<string> userNames;
    private Files file;

    public AddFileForm()
    {
        file = new Files();
        userNames = new List<string>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public AddFileForm(List<string> _userNames)
    {
        this.userNames = _userNames;
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxUserList.DataSource = _userNames;
    }

    private AddFileForm(Files _file)
    {
        this.file = _file;
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxUserList.SelectedValue = _file.userName;
        listBoxItems.SelectedValue = _file.directory;
    }
```

Passing data from first form works fine, but the problem starts when I try to pass data from listBoxUserList and listBoxItems to database using stored-procedures. I'm adding data to listBoxItems manually. NullReferenceException occur on a button click, here:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxUserList.SelectedItems.Count != 0 && listBoxItems.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
            file.userName = listBoxUserList.SelectedValue.ToString();
            file.directory = listBoxItems.SelectedValue.ToString();
                try
                {
                    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
                    connection.AddFile(file);

                    MessageBox.Show("File added to database.");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed database connection!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First, select items to add to database");
            }
        }
```

Value from both listBoxes is not null, I have checked this. The main problem probably is in class constructor. My stored procedure works fine, when I was comment constructor who passing data from first form, it perfectly passing data to database. So, what's wrong? What i should do with constructors of class, it will work property in both cases?

I'm pasting error details

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Odwołanie do obiektu nie zostało ustawione na wystąpienie obiektu.
  Source=FilesEncoding
  StackTrace:
       w FilesEncoding.AddFileForm.buttonAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w C:\Users\Grabarz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FilesEncoding\FilesEncoding\AddFileForm.cs:wiersz 110
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       w System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       w FilesEncoding.Program.Main() w c:\users\grabarz\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FilesEncoding\FilesEncoding\Program.cs:wiersz 18
       w System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       w System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       w Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you checked that the SelectedValue of listBoxUserList is not null? Maybe you are trying to access it without selecting something on the listbox.

Comment: The problem is not that `listBoxUserList.SelectedValue.ToString()` is null, the problem is that here `file.userName`, `file` is null. Try to assign anything to `file.userName` and you will see. Also, please show the complete method where you call the line that throws the `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Thanks for answers. I edited my question. It just button click, both list cannot be null, I additional have there if statment, nullreferenceexception shows in his body, on try to assign value to file.username string. When I remove `public AddFileForm(List<string> _userNames)` with his body, my code works fine. It looks like multiple constructors with the same parameters may working bad.

Comment: Your code is suspicious with major differences in what each constructor initialize... The usage of member variables (`userNames` and `file`) is also suspicious since in your add handler you always add the same object if the button is clicked multiple times and since value set by the constructor seems to never be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, is this code correct, but finally it start to work! I've got similar solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624413/c-sharp-constructor-parameter-passing) but I don't know what's are diffrents between constructor in my topic question, and this. In my opinion my first record should work perfectly too. Here's my code:

```
private string userName;
private string fileDirectory;

public AddFileForm(Files _file) : this(_file.userName, _file.directory) {  }
public AddFileForm(string user, string directory)
{
    userName = user;
    fileDirectory = directory;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = listBoxUserList.SelectedItem.ToString();
    fileDirectory = listBoxItems.SelectedItem.ToString();
        try
        {
            Files file = new Files();
            file.userName = userName;
            file.directory = fileDirectory;
            DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
            connection.AddFile(file);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed database connection!");
        }
    }
```